# get start/end indexes of all words in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get the start/end indexes of all the words in a string

I tried:

```
let txt="hello here are some words";

const reg = new RegExp(/[(\s|\.)]/, 'i');

while (match = reg.exec(txt)) {
    console.log('from: '+match.index+' to:'+(match.index+match.input.length))
}
```

but this just goes into an endless loop

any help ?

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: One observation: you can't make a group inside a set `[]` and the OR `|` is implicit within the set so `|` will be taken litterally as `"|"`!

Comment: Do you need the starting and ending letter for all words in a string?

Comment: It's because of the absence of `g` flag on regex. See [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches). Use [`/[(\s|\.)]/gi`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/609wh86n/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 var regex=/\w+/g;    
    var txt="hello here are some words";
    var matchStr=null;
       while((matchStr=regex.exec(txt))!=null){
   console.log(matchStr[0]+'\tfrom: '+matchStr.index+' to:'+regex.lastIndex);
  }
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

You use "=" sign in the while loop. You should have == instead.

"=" is an assignment, `"x = 3"` -> x is 3.

"==" is an comparison `"x == 3"` -> is x equal to 3? If x is 3 it will give "TRUE"